# eslint error showing with webpack alias

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

In my `webpack` config. I defined aliases

```
alias: {
            components: 'src/components/',
            config: 'src/config/'
}
```

When I import a module from this path an eslint error occurred.

```
import ShadowWrapper from 'components/ShadowWrapper'
```

error 'components' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S components' to add it import/no-extraneous-dependencies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by using the [eslint-import-resolver-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-webpack)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192).

Answer (score 17):

Thanks, Pranav for the solution to this issue!
I add some code to this post to make it more practical for others.
First of all, in webpack config file I had defined this alias:

```
alias:{
  components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "components")
}
```

That allow me to import components in my app in that way:

```
import NewsFeed from 'components/NewsFeed'
```

I have installed `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` plugin and put below code into .eslintrc.js or .eslintrc file  :

```
settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['components', './src/components']
        ]
      }
    }
```

That's it after running linter I got rid of `Unable to resolve path to module 'components/NewsFeed'` error message
Hope it will be helpful for some of you!

Comment: Turns out, starting the path in the `eslint` config with `./` was crucial. In the example above, just using `'src/components'` won't work, even though you might assume they'd be equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what worked for me:

1. I installed **[eslint-import-resolver-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-alias)** as dev dependency:

   npm install eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-alias --save-dev
2. In the **Webpack config** (in my case, it was Vue config, which is merged with Webpack config by Vue-cli), I added a few aliases:

   ```
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.less'],
        alias: {
            Site: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/site'),
            Admin: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/admin'),
            Common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common'),
            Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common/assets'),
            Configs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common/configs'),
            Style: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common/style')
        }
    }
   ```
3. In the **.eslintsrc** (or .eslintsrc.js, if you use that), I added the plugin and maps for these aliases, as follows:

   ```
   "extends": ["plugin:import/recommended"],
   "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "alias": {
                "map": [
                    ["Site", "./src/site"],
                    ["Admin", "./src/admin"],
                    ["Common", "./src/common"],
                    ["Assets", "./src/common/assets"],
                    ["Configs", "./src/common/configs"],
                    ["Style", "./src/common/style"]
                ]
            },
            "extensions": [".js", ".less", ".json", ".vue"]
        }
   }
   ```

I have added extensions for clarity and some good measures, which you can choose to not use for yourself.

**Optional:**

If you use **VS Code** and want these aliases working with the path intellisense, add a file **jsconfig.json** at the root, and specify your alias paths:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["src/*"],
            "Root/*": ["src/*"],
            "Site/*": ["src/site/*"],
            "Admin/*": ["src/admin/*"],
            "Common/*": ["src/common/*"],
            "Assets/*": ["src/common/assets/*"],
            "Configs/*": ["src/common/configs/*"],
            "Style/*": ["src/common/style/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

There are additional settings for React and Typescript. Check the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) at official site.

Comment: Funny how even if my project uses webpack (with eslint), `eslint-import-resolver-alias` allowed me to get rid of linting errors in contrast with `eslint-import-resolver-webpack`

Comment: This one worked for me as well, I needed to install this package in addition to updating the eslint config.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, without mapping aliases between `webpack.config.js` and `.eslintrc`.

You can use `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` and setup you `.eslintrc` file like this:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:import/recommended"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": [
          "node_modules",
          "src"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I had to use multiple ways to tell my project I needed my aliases, I had to use the package.json way with __moduleAliases, like so

```
"_moduleAliases": {
"@root": ".",
"@sApi": "./Server/api",
"@sApp": "./Server/app",
"@sCtrl": "./Server/controller",
"@sData": "./Server/data",
"@sDoc": "./Server/doc",
"@sError": "./Server/error",
"@sLog": "./Server/log",
"@sLog-w":"./Server/log/winston",
"@sMid-dto": "./Server/middleware/dto",
"@sMid-jSche": "./Server/middleware/schema",
"@sMid-utils": "./Server/middleware/utils"
```

}

I had to use createAliasSettings with path like so :

```
...createAliasSetting({
  '@sApi': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/api'),
  '@sApp': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/app'),
  '@sCtrl': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/controller'),
  '@sData': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/data'),
  '@sDoc': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/doc'),
  '@sError': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/error'),
  '@sLog': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/log'),
  '@sLog-w': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/log/winston'),
  '@sMid-dto': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/middleware/dto'),
  '@sMid-jSche': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/middleware/schema'),
  '@sMid-utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './Server/middleware/utils'),
}),
```

and the eslint-import-resolver-alias like so :

```
'import/resolver': {
  alias: {
    map: [
      ['@sApi', './Server/api'],
      ['@sApp', './Server/app'],
      ['@sCtrl', './Server/controller'],
      ['@sData', './Server/data'],
      ['@sDoc', './Server/doc'],
      ['@sError', './Server/error'],
      ['@sLog', './Server/log'],
      ['@sLog-w', './Server/log/winston'],
      ['@sMid-dto', './Server/middleware/dto'],
      ['@sMid-jSche', './Server/middleware/schema'],
      ['@sMid-utils', './Server/middleware/utils'],
    ],
    extentions: ['.js', '.json'],
  },
},
```

if I omit one of the 3 ways it does not work I dont know why but it works like this. I'm using es5 syntax and it works fine, the only thing that does not work is, lets say i'm in /a.js and I do const b = require('@b/index') it won't bring me to the index file in the folder that is linked to the b-alias but I guess it is ok, if you think I could do better with my config, let me know :)